# Sitecore PowerShell script to get all images where the File Path is empty

Tags: powershell-extensions

I'm writing a Sitecore PowerShell script to get all images (without their Media Folders) under the path `master:\sitecore\media library`, where the `File Path` in the `Media` section is empty, like the following image

[image]

This is my code

```
$path = "master:\sitecore\media library"
$items = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.TemplateID -ne [Sitecore.TemplateIDs]::MediaFolder }

$items | ForEach-Object {
   Write-Host "Item name: " $_.Name  
}
```

I need to add another condition to get all images with empty file path but I don't know how to do it, I'm a newbie with Sitecore.

I use Sitecore 8.2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to add a filter for filepath empty: `([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_.Fields["File Path"]))`
The final query will be:

```
$path = "master:\sitecore\media library"
$items = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.TemplateID -ne [Sitecore.TemplateIDs]::MediaFolder -and ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_.Fields["File Path"]))}

$items | ForEach-Object {
   Write-Host "Item name: " $_.Name  $_.Paths.FullPath
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much.